# Can't get navigation bar to center

Tags: css, html, centering

Have tried a lot of different things but can not figure out why it won't center. Any help would be awesome!

```css
nav {
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  color: #F55F5F;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a>
      <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things to center the `ul`:

1. Add `text-align: center` to the `nav` to center the `ul` inside it.
2. Reset the default left padding of `ul`

See demo below:

```css
nav {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  color: #F55F5F;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a>
      <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nav{
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just put text align center to nav

```
 nav {
     text-align: center;
  }
```